# Can't load themify icon font from my Namecheap server.

Tags: html, css, server, icon-fonts

I hope you all are having a good day.

I currently have a wired problem with my code. 
I have designed an HTML5 template which includes Themify icon fonts.  I have added it locally, and it's working fine in every browser.  Once I uploaded the project to my Namecheap server, I noticed that the browser couldn't load Themify icon files and show this error into my console panel.

index.html:388 GET http://example.com/mtest/light/fonts/themify.woff?-fvbane net::ERR_ABORTED
 index.html:1 GET http://example.com/mtest/light/fonts/themify.ttf?-fvbane net::ERR_ABORTED

I have tried a different server with the same code, and it's working without any issue.

**I have added two screenshots from two different hosting you can see.**

I will appricate any help with the problem.

[Working Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOz6V.png)

[Error Screensot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRW1P.png)

Comment: It is possible that your server doesn't know how to handle woff or ttf files? You have to set their MIME types in the server control panel.

Comment: Hello there, Thanks for your answer.it was very helpful. I googled about that and found so many things, and it made me confused. Can you please guide me through the process how can I solve this problem by adding MIME Type in my cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

It'a security problem

> It appears your application or the part of the application is using older version of PHP, which is marked to vulnerabilities because further update are not longer available for those. Try using the newer version of PHP for the application and check if you end up getting the same blocking via the ModSecurity rule..

https://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1690878

**UPDATE:**
It seems that deleting this part of the URL can solve the problem

> ?-fvbane